# Custom Post Types (Changing post style based on category)

Tags: custom-post-types

thanks for your attention.

I have a custom post type I've built called "Portfolio Items". These posts layout a nice 6 column grid and are contained within 4 different categories.

I've created 4 separate pages and each page will have its own page template.

The page template will be different for each page. Depending on the page and category I setup in each template should change the style of a post and remove the hyperlink.

```
<?php 
$items = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1
)); 
while ( $items->have_posts() ) : 
   $items->the_post();
   $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
 ?>

<?php
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );
?>

<?php 
if ( in_category( 'print' )) { ?>

    <a href="#port-<? the_ID(); ?>" data-toggle="modal">
    <div class="span2" id="square" style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?>); background-size:100%;  background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;">
    <span>
      <h3>
        <?php the_title();?>
      </h3>
    </span>
   </div>
    </a>

<?php } else { ?>

    <div class="span2" id="square" style="background:#000;">
    <span>
      <h3>
        <?php the_title();?>
      </h3>
    </span>
   </div>

<?php } ?>
```

( Pastebin of the same code: http://pastebin.com/NnpW24AY )

I'm trying to tell it that if the post is in a certain category, then it should display as it was intended, else, it should not have a hyperlink and the background should be black.

All this does right now is duplicates the post, leaving the original. So what I have is the regular post, then a black box post without a hyperlink next to it.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code seems to work for me. The output toggles by category as I would expect. If there is a problem I don't think it is in the code you posted on the pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the

endwhile

Maybe you didn't copy/paste it in, but if it's not in your file you'll want to add it.

Comment: While you may be right, this is not really an asnwer to the question. Once you [get a little bit of rep](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) you can post comments.